# React; calculate dynamically the total time of a playlist after each add/remove of track

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am relatively new to React, and this is the first full project I am making, inside the Codecademy Pro path "Full Stack Engineer".
The goal was to create a React website to fetch tracks with the Spotify API and then create playlists to save them on Spotify.

Inside the App --> Playlist Components, I want to add a dynamic total time calculator for the playlist: each time a track is added or removed, the total time is updated.

For this, I have:

```
fetched the duration_ms in Spotify.js
displayed the duration of the song in minutes (defined in Playlist.js)
```

Now I have added a new feature in the App.js as useState: totalTime and setTotalTime, by default on ‘0:0’.

I passed the props from App.js down to Playlist.js and then to my new function Component Time.js

In this Time.js, I am rendering an HTML element where I display the total time (props.totalTime), and define a function that should update the state totalTime each time the playlist tracks state is changed, using the useCallback from ‘react’.

Problem: nothing happens!
In DevTools, I see that props. tracks are indeed in Time Component, and I already tested my function separately with hard-coded arguments.

Have anyone ideas where the problem could be?

Here are my files:

App.js

```
import React, { useState, useCallback, useEffect } from "react";
import "./App.css";

import Playlist from "../Playlist/Playlist";
import SearchBar from "../SearchBar/SearchBar";
import SearchResults from "../SearchResults/SearchResults";
import Spotify from "../../util/Spotify";

const App = () => {
  const [searchResults, setSearchResults] = useState([]);
  const [playlistName, setPlaylistName] = useState("New Playlist");
  const [playlistTracks, setPlaylistTracks] = useState([]);
  const [totalTime, setTotalTime] = useState(0+':'+0);

  const search = useCallback((term) => {
    Spotify.search(term).then(setSearchResults);
  }, []);

  const addTrack = useCallback(
    (track) => {
      if (playlistTracks.some((savedTrack) => savedTrack.id === track.id))
        return;

      setPlaylistTracks((prevTracks) => [...prevTracks, track]);
    },
    [playlistTracks]
  );

  const removeTrack = useCallback((track) => {
    setPlaylistTracks((prevTracks) =>
      prevTracks.filter((currentTrack) => currentTrack.id !== track.id)
    );
  }, []);

  const updatePlaylistName = useCallback((name) => {
    setPlaylistName(name);
  }, []);

  const savePlaylist = useCallback(() => {
    const trackUris = playlistTracks.map((track) => track.uri);
    Spotify.savePlaylist(playlistName, trackUris).then(() => {
      setPlaylistName("New Playlist");
      setPlaylistTracks([]);
    });
  }, [playlistName, playlistTracks]);





  return (
    <div>
      <h1>
        Ja<span className="highlight">mmm</span>ing
      </h1>
      <div className="App">
        <SearchBar onSearch={search} />
        <div className="App-playlist">
          <SearchResults searchResults={searchResults} onAdd={addTrack} />
          <Playlist
            playlistName={playlistName}
            playlistTracks={playlistTracks}
            onNameChange={updatePlaylistName}
            onRemove={removeTrack}
            onSave={savePlaylist}
            totalTime={totalTime}
            handleTime = {setTotalTime}
            
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

PlayList.js:

```
import React, { useCallback, useEffect } from "react";

import "./Playlist.css";

import TrackList from "../TrackList/TrackList";
import Time from "../Time/Time";


const Playlist = (props) => {
  const handleNameChange = useCallback(
    (event) => {
      props.onNameChange(event.target.value);
    },
    [props.onNameChange]
  );

  

  return (
    <div className="Playlist">
      <input onChange={handleNameChange} defaultValue={"New Playlist"} />
      <TrackList
        tracks={props.playlistTracks}
        isRemoval={true}
        onRemove={props.onRemove}
      />
<br/>
       <Time onChange={props.setTotalTime} totalTime={props.totalTime} tracks= {props.playlistTracks} />
      <button className="Playlist-save" onClick={props.onSave}>
        SAVE TO SPOTIFY
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Playlist;
```

Time.js

```
import React, {useCallback} from "react";

const Time =(props) => {
   
    
      const handleTotalTime = useCallback(()=> {
          let totalTime = 0;
         
            props.tracks.forEach((track)=> {
              totalTime += track.duration_ms;
            })
         
       
          const minutes = Math.floor(totalTime/60000);
          const seconds = ((totalTime % 60000) /1000).toFixed(0);
           let newTime = minutes + ':' + (seconds < 10 ? '0': '') + seconds;
        
            
        props.setTotalTime(newTime);
           
         
        
        }, [props.tracks]); 
      
    

    return (

        <span>Your Playlist Total Time is currently: <input value={props.totalTime} onChange={handleTotalTime} /></span>
    );
}

export default Time;
```

As the function works in isolation with hard-coded arguments, the problem could come from the props and their respective naming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The total time is calculated by summing the current times of the tracks, and not by editing an `input`.

Since the value of `totalTime` is computed from the `tracks` array, you don't need another state, so remove this:

```
const [totalTime, setTotalTime] = useState(0+':'+0);
```

In the `PlayList` compute the `totalTime` by calling the `computeTotalTime` function, and pass it to the `Time` component. Change the `Time` component to a simple display component by removing the `input` and the logic.

```
const computeTotalTime = tracks => {
  let totalTime = 0;

  props.tracks.forEach((track) => {
    totalTime += track.duration_ms;
  })

  const minutes = Math.floor(totalTime / 60000);
  const seconds = ((totalTime % 60000) / 1000).toFixed(0);
  return minutes + ':' + (seconds < 10 ? '0' : '') + seconds;
};

const Playlist = (props) => {
  const handleNameChange = useCallback(
    (event) => {
      props.onNameChange(event.target.value);
    },
    [props.onNameChange]
  );
  
  const totalTime = computeTotalTime(props.playlistTracks)

  return (
    <div className="Playlist">
      <input onChange={handleNameChange} defaultValue={"New Playlist"} />
      <TrackList
        tracks={props.playlistTracks}
        isRemoval={true}
        onRemove={props.onRemove}
      />
<br/>
       <Time totalTime={totalTime} />
      <button className="Playlist-save" onClick={props.onSave}>
        SAVE TO SPOTIFY
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

const Time = ({ totalTime }) => (
  <span>Your Playlist Total Time is currently: {totalTime}</span>
)
```

Comment: It works if I put the function computeTotalTime outside of the const Playlist (I think because at the beginning there are no props to be passed, and the .forEarch returns an error), thank you !